# Unable to process the uploaded files for analytic name - id and version - v1. Check the documentation on how to develop Python analytic

Tags: predix

I am trying to publish my analytics to predix but i am getting this error.

> Unable to process the uploaded files for analytic name - *****ID**** and version - v1. Check the documentation on how to develop Python analytic. Also verify that supported language for analytic should be Python.

I am new to this one If somebody can help me on this.

config.json

```
{
  "entry-method": "analytic.EDC_Cracker.predict",
  "non-conda-libs": [
    "boto"
  ],
  "conda-libs": [
    "scikit-learn",
    "dill",
    "tensorflow",
    "Keras",
    "numpy",
    "scipy",
    "pandas"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a sample python analytic here.
https://github.com/PredixDev/predix-analytics-sample

You can find a tutorial here.
https://www.predix.io/resources/tutorials/journey.html#1615

The docs are here
https://docs.predix.io/en-US/content/service/analytics_services/analytics_framework/overview

You might get more responses here:
https://www.predix.io/community/forum

Comment: Thanks for these useful resources